# GitHub I cannot add a reviewer to a pull request

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

I am the owner of a public GitHub repository but I cannot add anyone to review my pull request. It only shows "Nothing to show".
I tried what was suggested on another similar question = to add a collaborator to the repository. But I cannot add myself, supposedly because I am the owner of the repository.

Comment: I think I got it. While "approve" option cannot be selected in the review section, passing the mouse on it shows "Pull request authors cannot review their own pull request".

Comment: Since it is your own repo and there are no other contributors, you can push the changes directly to master instead of a seperate branch ?

Comment: Indeed. I was following an online course ant the teacher had actually 2 gitHub accounts that was the reason why at one point I was no longer able to do the same as the video.